# How do I create the small icon next to the website tab for my site?

Tags: html

I've been wondering how to code something I don't know what it's called. Basically, (I don't have enough reputation to insert an image), it's the little icon next to your tab showing what website you're on. Like on facebook it's the "f" with blue background and google is the "g" with the colors... :\

Could anyone please help me with how to implement it on my website and what it's called? Thanks so much

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is called favicon.ico and you can generate it from this site.

http://www.favicon.cc/

Comment: be sure to delete cache after - to see it

Comment: Once you have a generated image add this into your `<head>` tag: `<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="http://example.com/myicon.png">`

Comment: many brwosers also automagically check if domain/favicon.ico exists

Answer (score 30):

This is for the icon in the browser (most of the sites omit the type):

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon"
     href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" />
```

or

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png"
     href="http://example.com/image.png" />
```

or

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon"
     href="http://example.com//apple-touch-icon.png">
```

for the shortcut icon:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon"
     href="http://example.com/favicon.ico" />
```

Place them in the `<head></head>` section.

Edit may 2019 some additional [examples from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#Providing_icons_for_different_usage_contexts)

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally down voted and SO won't let me undo. I up voted one of your other answers to add the point back.

Comment: For the first example, with ``rel="icon"`` and ``href="http://example.com/favicon.ico"``, as far as I know, that is what web servers do by default.  So usually one can simply put a file called "favicon.ico" in the site's root directory and then it isn't necessary to add this ``<link>`` tag to the source for every page.

Comment: @RayButterworth It is not the server, it is the browser. Yes, you can omit it, and if the browser finds favicon.ico will use it. If the browser don't find such file it will use a default one - in Windows I think it is the _blank file_.